# Get numbers from string TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What is the easiest way to split NVARCHAR with numbers into **int**'s? For example 1, 2 and 3 from "123".

Comment: Could you give a complete example of what you're trying to do? Split it into rows? columns? something else?

Comment: Use a tool designed to do it, like a scripting language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a note, you can also do this with a recursive CTE:

```
with val as (
      select '123' as val
     ),
     cte as (
      select left(val, 1) as c, substring(val, 2, len(val)) as rest
      from val
      union all
      select  left(rest, 1), substring(rest, 2, len(rest))
      from cte
      where rest <> ''
     )
select c
from cte;
```

Comment: Charlie Rosenfeld, if you have smallstrings like '123'. I think you should use Gordon's solution instead of the one above, this will be faster. @Gordon Linoff: Am I right 'Commissioner' Gordon?
On another note, Sir I am a fan. I have read many solution given by you.

Comment: In the event that an empty string is passed in this will return a single row with an empty string. Easily changed by adding `where len(val) > 0` to the anchor member in `cte`. Out of curiosity, I tried changing the recursive CTE to use `substring` to extract the character and a count to move through the string, thus avoiding the overhead of `rest`. The result: exactly the same execution plan.

Comment: @DeepanshuKalra . . . To see which is faster, you need to do a time comparison.  I added this just in case someone is uncomfortable about using `master..spt_values`.  On a small string, it might be faster, but I don't really know.

Comment: Additionally, the recursive CTE has a default number of recursions before it will error. I think it's around 100. You can tell the query to ignore the default, though.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you want it to 'Split it into rows'. You can use the code below:

```
DECLARE @var varchar(10) = 123;
--DECLARE @var varchar(10) = 'charlie';

SELECT SUBSTRING(Temp.input, v.number+1, 1) 
FROM (SELECT @var input) Temp
JOIN MASTER..spt_values v ON v.number < LEN(Temp.input)
WHERE v.TYPE = 'P'
```

Output:

[image]