# After splitting the string have to insert in to table column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this split function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION SplitString
    (@Input NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @Character CHAR(1))
RETURNS @Output TABLE (Item NVARCHAR(1000))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @StartIndex INT, @EndIndex INT

    SET @StartIndex = 1

    IF SUBSTRING(@Input, LEN(@Input) - 1, LEN(@Input)) <> @Character
    BEGIN
        SET @Input = @Input + @Character
    END

    WHILE CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @EndIndex = CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input)

        INSERT INTO @Output(Item)
            SELECT SUBSTRING(@Input, @StartIndex, @EndIndex - 1)

        SET @Input = SUBSTRING(@Input, @EndIndex + 1, LEN(@Input))
    END

    RETURN
END
GO
```

I want to use this function in a stored procedure, the procedure is doing an insert:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (KEY, description) 
VALUES (SELECT Ident_current('table2'),
        SELECT item FROM webreports.Splitstring('A','B','C') )
```

The target table has two columns `Key` and `Description`. `Key` column is sourced from other identity column table, and `Description` column is to be inserted from the result of the function, a sub-string.

The procedure is not working properly.

Answer (score 2):

No need to use `VALUES`:

```
INSERT INTO table1 ([key], descrption) 
SELECT 
    IDENT_CURRENT('table2'), 
    item 
FROM dbo.SplitString('A,B,C', ',')
```

---

As a side note, your `SplitString` function is not optimal. You should be doing this is a set-based fashion rather than RBAR. Aaron Bertrand wrote an article on different ways to split strings. You can read it [here.](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)

Comment: @SivaRajini Please consider replacing your `SplitString` function.

Comment: @SivaRajini a better way to Split string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32023825/get-numbers-from-string-tsql/32024315#32024315